# Removing opposite lists from list of lists

Tags: python, list

I need to remove from a list of lists all the opposite couples of lists. For example, if my list of lists is `l = [[1], [-1], [-1], [2], [2], [2], [-2]]`, and I need to remove the couple of opposite lists, the output should be `l_out = [[-1], [2], [2]]`, because I remove a `[1], [-1]` and a `[2], [-2]`. How can I do this procedure recursively with a loop?

Comment: This is really strange, why do you have a bunch of single element lists inside a list?

Comment: It is just a simple example, in reality I have more than one element in each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter


l = [[1], [-1], [-1], [2], [2], [2], [-2]]

c = Counter(v for (v, ) in l)
out = [[v] for v in c for _ in range(c.get(v, 0)-c.get(-v, 0))]

print(out)
```

Prints;

```
[[-1], [2], [2]]
```

Comment: Ah, that's clever, but I believe it loses the order, no? That is the order will always be the order that the numbers are first encountered (assuming insertion-order dicts). Note sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

So, to do this efficiently, you can keep track of the opposite in a dict along with the index it was encountered. When building up the resulting list, use `None` to mark spots that need to be deleted, and just do a second pass to filter out nones, making keeping track of the indices much easier:

```
In [1]: data  = [[1], [-1], [-1], [2], [2], [2], [-2]]

In [2]: seen = {}

In [3]: result = []
   ...: default = 0, None
   ...: for i, (x,) in enumerate(data): # again, why single lists?
   ...:     n, j = seen.get(-x, default)
   ...:     if n == 0:
   ...:         seen[-x] = 1, i
   ...:         result.append([x])
   ...:     elif n == 1:
   ...:         seen[-x] = 0, i
   ...:         result.append(None)
   ...:         result[j] = None
   ...:

In [4]: result
Out[4]: [[1], None, None, None, None, [2], [-2]]

In [5]: [x for x in result if x is not None]
Out[5]: [[1], [2], [-2]]
```

So, this is still linear time, albeit, using auxiliary, linear space.

Answer (score 0):

You could pop from the back as well.

```
l = [[1], [-1], [-1], [2], [2], [2], [-2]]
i = len(l)-1
if i%2==0:
    i=i-1
while i>0:
    l.pop(i)
    i-=2
    
print(l)
```

Comment: this just removes every other element... that isn't what the OP needs to do, although admittedly the OP wasn't very clear. This is also quadratic time... and generally you would just do this with slicing, `l[1::2]` which would be linear.